# How to add a label on the checkbox simple_form and style the label inline to the checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I have a checkbox which doesn't have a label. How do I add a label tag in simple_form where the checkbox is inserted in the HTML label tag.

I currently have checkbox and plain text after it.

```
    <%= f.check_box :is_positive, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %> Is positive?
```

I tried the below code, but it makes the label higher than the actual checkbox.

```
    <%= f.input :is_positive, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, inline_label: 'Is positive?' %>
```

Is there a way to label the checkbox and have its label inline to the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below and you can use `css` to change the style of your label to whatever you like:

```
<%= f.label :is_positive do %>
  <%= f.check_box :is_positive, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %> <span class="labelText">Is positive?</span>
<% end %>
```